# python pyodbc query loop only returns one result

Tags: python, for-loop, pyodbc

I've included the code below. Basically, I have a table (called `forumPosts`) that has the columns `user_id`,`children`,`content`,`id`. `children` is a string of ids for `forumPosts` that are follow up forum posts (I'm not in charge of organizing children posts into the same table as parent posts). This string is formatted like `'["id1","id2",...]'`.

My goal is to produce a data set that looks like:

```
parent_user_id,child_user_id_1,child_user_id_2,...
```

The issue here is that the below code only prints a single output. Why does it do this? Thanks for your help.

```
import pyodbc


#connect to database, create db cursor
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('cnxnstring', autocommit=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

for row in cursor.execute("select user_id,children from myTable where children!='[]' and user_id!='null'"):
    children=row[1].replace('"','').replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',')
    userid=row[0]
    for child in children:
        print cursor.execute("select user_id from myTable where id = ?",child).fetchone()
```

sample data for the columns requested:

```
  id           |  user_id    |  children
hgjegh4pjbr44p | gd6v7134AUa | ["asdf34dfg3sdfq", "asdegh4pjbrxx3"]
asdegh4pjbrxx3 | xzf7134AUax | ["hgjegh4pjbr44p"]
hgjegh4pjbr44p | NULL        | []
asdf34dfg3sdfq | adfcv34skax | []
```

Comment: Haven't been able to reproduce your problem. Can you provide a set of sample data for the `user_id`, `id`, and `children` columns?

Comment: @tnt I guess you didn't read the part where I said I wasn't in charge of the database design.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Using the sample data provided, the output is:

```
('adfcv34skax', )
None
```

A row for `asdegh4pjbrxx3` ID is not returned because of leading whitespace. This can be observed by changing the last `print` line to:

```
print child
```

Which outputs:

```
asdf34dfg3sdfq
 asdegh4pjbrxx3
hgjegh4pjbr44p
```

`'  asdegh4pjbrxx3'` isn't equal to `'asdegh4pjbrxx3'`, which returns a null result.

### Solution

Replace the `children` assignment line with the following to strip necessary characters and whitespace:

```
children=[child.strip('"[] ') for child in row[1].split(',')]
```

I think a list comprehension with the single `strip` call is more readable than nested `replace`.

Alternately, [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) should work as well:

```
children=ast.literal_eval(row[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct on the assumption that the issue is in your children assignment.  You should introspect or print while in the for child in children loop to see whether or not your list comprehension is doing what you intend.  That's the funny thing about list comprehensions: they work, but don't do what you set out to do as your assumptions need to be flawless.  In this case, you aren't accounting for all possible outputs of the database your connecting to.  While you're at it, you may want to ensure your program deals with the character sets the parent database program can accept.